# DB2 Assign result of with clause to variable

Tags: db2

I am using DB2 LUW and want to a assign a result of a With clause to a variable in a stored procedure.

I got the exception

```
{0:0} An unexpected token "AS" was found following "l = (WITH BASE".  Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.28.11
```

Is it possible to assign the result on this way or should I have to solve it with a cursor?

```
DECLARE result CLOB(8M); 
SET result = (WITH BASE AS ( 
xxx
) 
SELECT JSON_ARRAY (select json_objects FROM ITEMS format json) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1);
```

Comment: Use `WITH .. AS (..) SELECT ... INTO result` instead.

Comment: Hmm, this does not work
`WITH TEMP AS (
SELECT IBMREQD FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)
SELECT * FROM TEMP INTO result; `
 I got this exception:
`{0:0} An unexpected token "WITH TEMP AS ( 
SELECT IBMRE" was found following "`

Comment: sorry, syntax would be `...select ... into result from temp`

Comment: yeah fine now, working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use instead the syntax style:

`with ctename AS ( ... ) SELECT ... INTO ... FROM ctename;`